# Change CollectionView position with animation but move back when first scroll

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I want to change my `collectionView` position when pressing a button. I wrapped the `collectionView` and `Button` in a `View` and used UIView animate to make it move up. It can move up successfully, but when I am scrolling `collectionView` it's return back to its original position. If I tried many times, it became normal and didn't move back again.

How could i fix this issue? Thank you for any advice.

```
func openPreview() {
    if !isPreviewOpened {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.previewView.frame.origin.y -= self.previewView.frame.height
            self.previewButton.frame.origin.y -= self.previewView.frame.height
        }
        isPreviewOpened = true
        updateUI()
}    

func closePreview() {
    if isPreviewOpened {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.previewView.frame.origin.y += self.previewView.frame.height
            self.previewButton.frame.origin.y += self.previewView.frame.height
        }
        isPreviewOpened = false
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking others, provide my solution to this question, hope it can help someone in the future.

This issue was happened because that the frame I changed conflicting with the auto layout I set earlier in storyboard. According to the document, I have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true to track the frames.

> By default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints that fully determine 
>        the view's position. This allows the auto layout system to track the frames of views whose 
>        layout is controlled manually (through -setFrame:, for example).
>        When you elect to position the view using auto layout by adding your own constraints, 
>        you must set this property to NO. IB will do this for you.

So this is the answer.

```
func openPreview() {
    if !isPreviewOpened {
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.previewView.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.maxY - self.previewView.frame.height
            self.previewButton.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.maxY - self.previewView.frame.height - self.previewButton.frame.height
        }
    }
}
```